# What is the test credit card number for Converge Payment Api?

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, payment

I have tried with lot of test credit card number but always get back the result is 'INVALID CARD'.

Request Url:

https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/processxml.do

Here is my Sample Xml Request:

```
"xmldata=<txn>
<ssl_merchant_ID>******</ssl_merchant_ID>
<ssl_user_id>***</ssl_user_id>
<ssl_pin>******</ssl_pin>
<ssl_transaction_type>ccsale</ssl_transaction_type>
<ssl_card_number>4111111111111111</ssl_card_number>
<ssl_exp_date>0120</ssl_exp_date>
<ssl_amount>7</ssl_amount>
<ssl_cvv2cvc2>123</ssl_cvv2cvc2>
<ssl_avs_address>test</ssl_avs_address>
<ssl_avs_zip>9999</ssl_avs_zip>
<ssl_first_name>test</ssl_first_name>
<ssl_last_name>test</ssl_last_name>
</txn>"
```

My Result:

```
<txn>
<ssl_approval_code />
<ssl_email />
<ssl_card_short_description>VISA</ssl_card_short_description>
<ssl_cvv2_response />
<ssl_last_name>test</ssl_last_name>
<ssl_avs_zip>9999</ssl_avs_zip>
<ssl_exp_date>0120</ssl_exp_date>
<ssl_account_balance>0.00</ssl_account_balance>
<Additional_Information />
<ssl_result_message>INVALID CARD</ssl_result_message>
<ssl_card_type>CREDITCARD</ssl_card_type>
<ssl_city />
<ssl_phone />
<ssl_avs_address>test</ssl_avs_address>
<ssl_first_name>test</ssl_first_name>
<Customer_Account />
<ssl_amount>7.00</ssl_amount>
<ssl_state />
<ssl_txn_id>230317B39-CA1A68F1-63A9-44C8-9812-88AD8DBA7D37</ssl_txn_id>
<ssl_result>1</ssl_result>
<ssl_card_number>41**********1111</ssl_card_number>
<ssl_txn_time>03/23/2017 12:13:37 AM</ssl_txn_time>
<ssl_avs_response />
<ssl_transaction_type>SALE</ssl_transaction_type>
</txn>
```

In This Example I have tried with `4111111111111111` Visa Card. Please tell me Converge have any other Test number. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: I would recommend [this site](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/) for generating CC numbers, designed for testing purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was getting Error # `9999` with the message `Only Test Cards Allowed`.

I found a sample on [Elavon's site](https://developer.elavon.com/#/api/eb6e9106-0172-4305-bc5a-b3ebe832f823.rcosoomi/versions/5180a9f2-741b-439c-bced-5c84a822f39b.rcosoomi/documents/?converge-integration-guide/book/api_introduction/getting_started.html) that had an example with the credit card number `5472063333333330`. Using this number, my tests were able to go through.

Comment: What PIN and credentials did you use for this? I'm getting:
`body errorCode=4025
errorName=Invalid Credentials
errorMessage=The credentials supplied in the authorization request are invalid.`

Comment: @santalurr I used the credentials [provided by Converge](https://www.besha2ready.com/converge#convergeapi): Merchant ID: `000127`, User ID: `ssltest`, PIN: `IERAOBEE5V0D6Q3Q6R51TG89XAIVGEQ3LGLKMKCKCVQBGGGAU7FN627GPA54P5HR`

Answer (score 3):

Just set test mode false, and now it's working fine,

```
<ssl_test_mode>False</ssl_test_mode>
```

Then test card no `4111111111111111`

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well, so I called Converge to find out. Unfortunately they do not have any test credit card numbers, however if you change

```
<ssl_transaction_type>ccsale</ssl_transaction_type>
```

to

```
<ssl_transaction_type>ccauthonly</ssl_transaction_type>
```

you can use a real credit card and it will only authorize the card for the amount, but will not debit/charge the card you use. Obviously you'll want to use this method over HTTPS so your personal credit card information is transmitted securely, but by doing ccauthonly you can effectively test your payment gateway without using real money.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have find another one solution, i  was set ssl_test_mode = true , `<ssl_test_mode>False</ssl_test_mode>` and it will accept all the test credit cards like 4111111111111111.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using production the 4111 visa number will give a decline. To get an approval you should use 5000300020003003 . Be sure to void these test cards as they will actually cause a real batch to fail. If you are using the demo environment call and get a test card number as they change periodically.